# python bit_length() of 0 returns unexpected value

Tags: python, binary, bit

Why does the bit length of 0 return 0 and not 1?

```
>>> int(0).bit_length()
0

>>> int(2).bit_length()
2
```

2 in binary is 0x10 which represents two bits, doesn't zero in binary still techincally take up 1 bit since its representation in hex is 0x0?

Comment: These are theoretical bounds. In practice, all integers are represented by some number of bytes, so you could just as well ask why `bit_length()` doesn't always return a non-zero multiple of 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python documentation states

> More precisely, if x is nonzero, then x.bit_length() is the unique
>   positive integer k such that 2**(k-1) <= abs(x) < 2**k. Equivalently,
>   when abs(x) is small enough to have a correctly rounded logarithm,
>   then k = 1 + int(log(abs(x), 2)).
>   If x is zero, then x.bit_length()
>   returns 0.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length

Comment: But is there a rationale for special-casing 0? Is there some use case they know of or anticipate where this behavior is desired? Or did they go out of their way to be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation on https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html
It is explained.
That's how the function works. if you send it 0, it'll output 0

> If x is zero, then x.bit_length() returns 0.